# Does using driveway pressure wash cleaner on my garage chip flooring damage it?

Tags: garage, cleaning

I needed to clean my garage floor and the only thing I had was Zep pressure washer cleaner for driveways and concrete. I then realized it wasn’t meant for certain types of surfaces. Did I damage my garage floor by using it? It seems to have lost some luster to it but wasn’t sure if that’s from before.

Photo of my garage floor now - assuming that’s chip flooring:

https://imgur.com/a/uhcgW7O

Comment: what was the surface coating

Comment: pressure washer have two modes, the gentle fan spray and the damaging point stream mode that can dig holes in concrete

Comment: Honestly I have no idea the coating. We bought the home and it was already done, but didn’t really pay attention to what the coating was exactly. 

I actually didn’t use my pressure washer (was too lazy) just used my hose and a mop to do a light clean using the solution.

Comment: what's the chemical content of the cleaner? I found one of the same brand that's apparently "tetrasodium EDTA", which looks like it mostly dissolves rust and corrosion, and shouldn't really interact with most non-metal surfaces at all.

Comment: I don't know, _has_ it damaged your floor? Is there an actual problem or are you just panicing about something that _might_ have happened, but for which there is no proof of having happened. If you don't see any damage, there probably wasn't.

Comment: There’s a noticeable less shine in areas where I didn’t wash. It’s a sodium hydroxide based cleaner so reading that it could damage the epoxy. Trying to figure out if it’s just a cosmetic damage or if I need to repair it.  Here’s a link to the product: https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZEP-128-oz-Driveway-and-Concrete-Pressure-Wash-Concentrate-Cleaner-ZUBMC128/202056505?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Those coatings are usually 2 part epoxy or paint, with glitter thrown on top at the last moment. You may have scrubbed off some of the glitter.

If the finish has turned gooey, then something’s wrong.